# WinForms Gradient (Image or By Code) - OnDraw Event

Tags: c#, winforms, coding-style, ondraw

Ok so im starting to get stuck into my design and get the style right.

My Theme is using a kryptonForm style GUI but kyryptonForms do not not have a pre designed ListView, so im having to build this myself

My Application is a messenger system based on XMPP/Jabber so you can guess how i would like my contact list to be designed.

i have done most of the positioning but im struggling on styling each contact row.

Im aiming for some transparent overlay simmerler to the MSN Live messenger Contact List

Heres my OnDraw Event code atm and im struggling to figure out the best way to do the gradient

```
private void ContactItem_OnPaintDraw(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {

        Rectangle ImageRect = e.Bounds;
        ImageRect.Inflate(-2, -2);
        ImageRect.Width = 32;

        Rectangle TextRect = e.Bounds;
        TextRect.X = ImageRect.Right + 2;
        TextRect.Width = e.Bounds.Width - TextRect.X;

        Rectangle IconRect = TextRect;
        IconRect.Inflate(-1, 0);
        IconRect.Y = ImageRect.Bottom - 16;
        IconRect.Width = 16;
        IconRect.Height = 16;

        if ((e.State & ListViewItemStates.Selected) != 0)
        {
            // Draw the background and focus rectangle for a selected item.
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(ContactListBackgroundBrush, e.Bounds);
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        }
        else
        {
            // Draw the background for an unselected item.
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.Bounds);
        }

        if (ListViewContacts.View != View.Details)
        {

            e.Graphics.DrawImage((Image)Resources.UserIconDefault, ImageRect);

            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Item.Text, e.Item.Font, TextRect, e.Item.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
        }
    }
```

And the `ContactListBackgroundBrush` var is like so

```
private Brush ContactListBackgroundBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(33, 162, 191));
```

its this that i need to convert to the styled element

[alt text http://screensnapr.com/u/yeq8o0.png](http://screensnapr.com/u/yeq8o0.png)

Im Looking to get this Highlighted style without importing any specific windows 7 DLL files as the App is used for windows XP as well.

Hope you guys can help me :)

Comment: Are you using Winforms? (I'm assuming that's what you're using due to the use of `DrawListViewItemEventArgs`) Probably a good idea to add "Winforms" to your tags list.  I'd probably be able to help if it were wpf...

Comment: Yea WinForms, Added to tag list, sorry about that. Thanks though

Comment: also added to your title, since it's relevant, and removed C#, which was not relevant.

Comment: Thankyou, im just half asleep to be honest, be working like 3 hours straight on trying to get this right, but there's not many docs I can find :( just need SO help now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a brush as a `LinearGradientBrush`, look for the [msnd documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.lineargradientbrush.aspx). This is IMHO the best way, to draw gradiants..